# Two errors in stored procedure: incorrect syntax near as expecting variable, must declare the scalar variable

Tags: sql-server

I created a stored procedure in SSMS 17.6

```
USE Stock
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE Add_Item
    @Name VARCHAR(20),
    @Section INT,
    @Size INT,
    @Grade INT,
    @Weight INT,
AS   // i get this error (incorrect syntax near as expecting variable)
    INSERT INTO [Item] ([Name_Item], [ID_SectionType], [SectionSize_Item],
                        [ID_Grade], [Weight])
    VALUES (@Name, @Section, @Size,
            @Grade, @Weight)
GO
```

I get this error

> Must declare the scalar variable

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the comma after the last parameter?

Comment: Side note: its also always a good idea to start any stored procedure with `set nocount on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-- you have extra comma after first variable before the AS, this fixes it 

Create Proc Add_Item

@Name varchar (20),
@Section int,
@Size int,
@Grade int,
@Weight int
AS --//i get this error (incorrect syntax near as expecting variable)
INSERT INTO [Item]
([Name_Item]
,[ID_SectionType]
,[SectionSize_Item]
,[ID_Grade]
,[Wight])
VALUES
(@Name
,@Section
,@Size
,@Grade
,@Weight)
GO
```